# How to handle Race Conditions in Behat/Mink

Tags: javascript, php, race-condition, behat, mink

So I have the following, very simply test in Behat/Mink. A button, when pressed, shows an element, which I then fill with some text. Sometimes this test works, sometimes it doesn't. Here's the basic structure:

`file.blade.php`

```html
<button id="show-inputs">Show</button>
<div id="inputs" class="hidden">
  <span>Input</span>
  <input type="text" id="test-input"/>
</div>
```

`script.js`

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('#show-inputs').on('click', function() {
    $('#inputs').removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

`TestingFeature.feature`

```
@javascript
Scenario: Testing Input Show/Fill
  Given I am on "/"
  Then I press "show-inputs"
  And I wait for javascript to finish loading
  Then I fill in "test-input" with "This is a Test"
  ...
```

`FeatureContext.php`

```php
public function iWaitForJavascriptToFinishLoading() {
  $this->getSession()->wait(10000, '$.active === 0');
}
```

As you can see, it's a simple test; after navigating to `/`, trigger click of `#show-inputs`, wait for JS to finish (i.e. give time to show `#inputs` div), then fill in `#test-input` with a simple test.

Running these tests, sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. Here's the output of `behat`:

```sh
...
Then I press "show-inputs"                        # FeatureContext::pressButton()
And I wait for javascript to finish loading       # FeatureContext::iWaitForJavascriptToFinishLoading()
Then I fill in "test-input" with "This is a Test" # FeatureContext::fillField()
  Element is not visible and can not be focused
```

The error `Element is not visible and can not be focused` only shows up sometimes, suggesting a race-condition on Show Element > Fill Element, happening in the incorrect order. I thought that `And I wait for javascript to finish loading`, which waits until `$.active` is `0` would handle this, but apparently it doesn't. I'm wondering if it has something to do with using a class `hidden` (`display:none`) vs a simple `$('{$selector}').show()`, but I'm not sure.

I can add a new check for something along the lines of `And I wait for "inputs" to be "visible"`, which waits until `$('{$selector}').is(':visible') === true`, but that doesn't feel right.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going the way I figured I would have to, using `And I wait for "test-input" to be "visible"`, with a custom definition in `FeatureContext.php`:

```php
/**
 * @Then I wait for :elementId to be :visibility
 */
public function iWaitForElementToBe($elementId, $visibility) {
  if ($visibility != 'visible' && $visibility != 'hidden') {
    throw new Exception("Invalid visibility pseudo `{$visibility}` supplied: Must be one of `visible`, `hidden`");
  }
  $this->getSession()->wait(1000, "\$('#{$elementId}').is(':{$visibility}') === true");
}
```

Then in `TestingFeature.feature:`

```
@javascript
Scenario: Testing Input Show/Fill
  Given I am on "/"
  Then I press "show-inputs"
  And I wait for "test-input" to be "visible"
  Then I fill in "test-input" with "This is a Test"
```

The only caveat is that if multiple elements are shown the same time, the `And I wait for ... to be ...` needs to be repeated for each element, even if they're toggled visible/hidden in the same line of code (such as `$('#id, #id2').removeClass('hidden')`).